# GAE (Python): How to get a key from StructuredProperty?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have these classes:

```
class X(ndb.Model):
  field1 = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)

class Y(ndb.Model):
  ref = ndb.StructuredProperty(X)
  field2 = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)

class Z(ndb.Model):
  refs = ndb.StructuredProperty(Y, repeated=True)
```

If I have a object of type `Z` called `z`then I can get a key for it by calling `z.key`. Assuming that I have some objects added to `z` field refs, how can I traverse then to get the keys for objects of type `X` and `Y`?

I have tried `z.refs[0].key`and `z.refs[0].ref.key`, but they return None. I can refer to `z.refs[0].field2` and `z.refs[0].ref.field1` just fine.

I have tried to switch StructuredProperty to LocalStructuredProperty, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the documentation on structured models](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured),

> Although the (structured model) instances are defined using the same syntax as for model classes, they are not full-fledged entities. They don't have their own keys in the Datastore. They cannot be retrieved independently of the ... entity to which they belong.

The reason that it works like this is that when you create an entity with a structured property, the structured property is expanded into new properties on the entity that contains it. After saving a Z entity to your datastore, take a look at the datastore viewer, and you'll see something like this for the entity:

```
Entity Key: ahxkZXZ-ZG9tYWluLW1hcmtldHBsYWNlLWRlYnVncg4LEgFaGICAgICAgOAJDA
ID: 5488762045857792
refs.field2 (list): [u'y1', u'y2']
refs.ref.field1 (list): [u'x1', u'x2']
```

Also, you'll note that if you change one of the field1/field2 values for the X/Y entities that you've saved to the datastore, the corresponding refs.ref.field1/refs.field2 values stored in the Z entity will not be updated, as the values in Z are not linked in any way back to the original X/Y entities.

Comment: If I want to be able to get the keys and see the changes in field1/field2, is my best option to use KeyProperty and then manually query for field2, subobjects and field1 in subjobjects?